# How to iterate values ​within queryset and return them to my model?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm trying to iterate a value in my queryset, but I have no idea where to start.

I explain the case more in detail.

My models.

```
class Tarifa_Sem(models.Model):
    limite_inferior_isr = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    limite_superior = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

class Calculadora_isr(models.Model):
    tarifa = models.ForeignKey(Tarifa_Sem, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    base_gravada = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    limite_inf_calculo = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
```

And my queryset:

```
def limite_inferior(self):
        qsl1 = Calculadora_isr.objects.values_list('base_gravada')
        qsl2 = Tarifa_Sem.objects.filter(Q(limite_superior__gte=qsl1) & Q(limite_inferior_isr__lte=qsl1)).distinct().values_list('limite_inferior_isr', flat=True)[0]
        return qsl2

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.limite_inf_calculo = self.limite_inferior()
        super (Calculadora_isr, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The problem is that I only get the calculations with the first object of my query.

```
<QuerySet [**(Decimal('10000.00')**,), (Decimal('1200.00'),), (Decimal('7000.00'),),>
```

[Here is a more detailed model of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMIyB.jpg)

I need help to know how to pass each value through the queryset if it is already created and update the information of each record

Comment: `qsl2 = Tarifa_Sem.objects.filter(Q(limite_superior__gte=qsl1) & Q(limite_inferior_isr__lte=qsl1)).distinct().values_list('limite_inferior_isr', flat=True)[0]` is only getting the first record.  The `[0]` is limiting the return to the 1 record

Comment: even if I do not put it, it throws me a single value                                           >>> qsl2 = Tarifa_Sem.objects.filter(Q(limite_superior__gte=qsl1) & Q(limite_inferior_isr__lte=qsl1)).values_list('limite_inferior_isr')
>>> qsl2
<QuerySet [(Decimal('8790.96'),)]>
>>>

Comment: So you want  `limite_superior` also in the result set???

Comment: Filter where base_gravada is less than 10000 AND the i_end_int value is greater than 10000.   /  where; gte = greater than equal to lte = less than equal to /
so I get the rank between both